# How to get selected value in JqueryUI Selectmenu from out of the Change function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

i need to get selected option value in JqueryUI SelectMenu out of change event, But i can't get value out of Change function or selectmenu function,
how to do it/

```
  var iSelectedValue;
  var map="";
    $("#drpRegionName").selectmenu({
        change: function (event, ui) {

           iSelectedValue = ui.item.value;

            console.log(iSelectedValue); //Working
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            map = $(this).val();
            console.log(map); //working
        }
    });
    console.log(map); // not working
    console.log($(iSelectedValue); // not working
```

out of the function its undefined.

Comment: `map` and `iSelectedValue`  variable gets assigned a value after `change`/`select` event. So your outside console return as `undefined`.

Comment: First of all `iSelectedValue` is declared with `var' in `change` function scope. So this variable is not visible outside of this scope. And as mentioned above  by @randomSoul `map` variable is declared outside of `change` function.

Comment: Whatever you want to do with this selected value, should happen _inside_ the `change` event callback function.

Comment: @randomSoul , i've tried it also but not working.

Comment: It will not work. Why would you want to access those variables outside?

Comment: @randomSoul I've multiple select boxes, so get all the selected values and store it in DB.

Comment: You can have an array and when your variables are populated with value after the event you can push the selected value in an array and then you can access it later at the time when you store it in a DB.

Comment: You can make a function to collect the selected value from each of the SelectMenu's. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example, based on https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#product-selection

```js
$(function() {
  var iSelectedValue;
  var map = "";

  function getValues(p) {
    var arr = [];
    $("select", p).each(function(i, el) {
      arr.push({
        id: $(el).attr("id"),
        value: $(el).val()
      });
    });
    return arr;
  }

  $("fieldset select").selectmenu({
    change: function(e, ui) {
      iSelectedValue = getValues($("fieldset"));
      console.log(iSelectedValue);
    }
  });

  iSelectedValue = getValues($("fieldset"));
  console.log(iSelectedValue);
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.overflow {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <label for="speed">Select a speed</label>
  <select name="speed" id="speed">
    <option>Slower</option>
    <option>Slow</option>
    <option selected="selected">Medium</option>
    <option>Fast</option>
    <option>Faster</option>
  </select>

  <label for="files">Select a file</label>
  <select name="files" id="files">
    <optgroup label="Scripts">
      <option value="jquery">jQuery.js</option>
      <option value="jqueryui">ui.jQuery.js</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Other files">
      <option value="somefile">Some unknown file</option>
      <option value="someotherfile">Some other file with a very long option text</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

  <label for="number">Select a number</label>
  <select name="number" id="number">
    <option>1</option>
    <option selected="selected">2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>13</option>
    <option>14</option>
    <option>15</option>
    <option>16</option>
    <option>17</option>
    <option>18</option>
    <option>19</option>
  </select>

  <label for="salutation">Select a title</label>
  <select name="salutation" id="salutation">
    <option disabled selected>Please pick one</option>
    <option>Mr.</option>
    <option>Mrs.</option>
    <option>Dr.</option>
    <option>Prof.</option>
    <option>Other</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

You can see here how we can update the Array when the page loads and then anytime a `change` event happens for one of the selectMenu items.

Hope that helps.